# Apache with Multiple vhosts. SSL to apply to only one of them

Tags: ssl, apache2, virtualhost

I run several websites using Apache 2 with VirtualHosts configured. They all work fine on their own (i.e. www.domain1.com, www.domain2.com, www.domain3.com).

One of these VHosts needs to run over HTTPS so has SSL setup with a wildcard domain (*.domain1.com), but it seems that the SSL port is also open for the other 2 domains: for example, I can access https://www.domain2.com. The issue is that obviously the browser issues a warning because the domain requested doesn't match the domain on the certificate.

What I would like to do is stop this behaviour altogether and block access to https to domain2.com and domain3.com. I understand that because of the actual protocol, you can't get the ServerName before having accepted the certificate and started decyphering the headers, but has anybody ever managed to get around that?

Thanks!

rafrafUk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the solution is having a unique ip adress per SSL site..

One ip for SSL vhost  (ie: 88.244.63.215)

http:// domain1.com   :80
https:// domain1.com  :443
https:// foo.domain1.com  :443

Another ip for Other vhosts (ie: 88.241.131.152)

http:// domain2.com   :80
http:// domain3.com   :80